# transition on click image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the width wise transition in image on clicking the image(size of image reduces slowly)

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function movediv(){
        var division = document.getElementById('image');
        division.style.width = "1000px";
        division.style.width ='600px' ;
        division.style.transition ='width  2s';
    }  
</head>
<body> 
    <img src = "generic_sky_wallpaper-1280x800.jpg" id="image" onclick="movediv();">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/L7Lvz/) will animate a friend of mine.

JS

```
$( ".imagediv" ).click(function(){

  $( "#minion" ).animate({
                          height: 400,
                          width: 300
                          }, 3000,
                         function() {
                                     // complete.
                                     });
                                 });
```